# simple remote ODBC database connection with ruby

Tags: ruby, database, odbc

I am attempting to make a simple connection to a remote database. I can not seem to get it to work.

```
remote_db = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:remote-host','user','password')
remote_db.table { |table| pp table }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Ruby DBI.
http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/

Here is an example of using DBI for ODBC connectivity:

```
# Require in the DBI files<br />
require 'DBI'

# create an ODBC connection instance<br />
dbi_conn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:datasource','your_username','your_password')

# query tables available  <br />
dbi_conn.tables

# returns an array with the results from a table TABLE:<br />
array_out = dbi_conn.select_all('SELECT * FROM TABLE')
```

some more in-depth info: 
http://www.kitebird.com/articles/ruby-dbi.html

Or, alternatively, you can use ruby-odbc:
http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/

Comment: i guess I am getting hung up on the datasource part.  Ill take a look.  Thanks for the links.

Comment: Rubyforge is gone now.

Comment: I am getting error "DBI::DatabaseError (IM002 (0) [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified)"

With command similar to
DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:MY_AS400', 'SVCJDADA', 'bgKky55Wao')