# Connecting to Vertica from Ruby

Tags: odbc, database-connection, ruby-1.9.2, vertica

I'm trying to use Ruby to connect to Vertica analytics DB (from linux machine). I've verified that connection is possible using `isql` and `unixodbc` (DSN defined in `/etc/odbc.ini`, based more or less on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6388549/187907)).

```
$ isql VerticaDSN
+--------------------------------------------+
| Connected!                                 |
|                                            |
| sql-statement                              |
| help [tablename]                           |
| quit                                       |
|                                            |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I have also installed [`vertica`](https://github.com/sprsquish/vertica), [`dbi`](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/ruby-dbi.html) and the [`ruby-odbc`](http://www.ch-werner.de/rubyodbc/odbc.html) gems (using ruby 1.9.2). I'm failing to connect with all of these, and I'm wondering if I might be doing something wrong or missing a dependency.

### using the vertica gem:

```
>> require 'vertica'
=> true
>> client = Vertica.connect({ :host => '10.0.0.15', :user => 'dbadmin', :password => 'pwd' })
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/vertica-0.8.1/lib/vertica/connection:31:in `initialize'
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/vertica-0.8.1/lib/vertica/connection:31:in `new'
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/vertica-0.8.1/lib/vertica/connection:31:in `connection'
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/vertica-0.8.1/lib/vertica/connection:24:in `initialize'
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/vertica-0.8.1/lib/vertica.rb:11:in `new'
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/vertica-0.8.1/lib/vertica.rb:11:in `connect'
```

### using DBI / ODBC gems:

(using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/835950/187907))

```
>> require 'dbi'
=> true
>> require 'odbc'
=> true
>> ODBC.datasources
=> [#<ODBC::DSN:0x0000000284c6f8 @name="VerticaDSN", @descr="\"test database\"">]
>> dbc = ODBC.connect('VerticaDSN')
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
    from (irb):15:in `initialize'
    from (irb):15:in `connect'
    from (irb):15
>> dbh = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:VerticaDSN', 'dbadmin', 'pwd')
DBI::InterfaceError: Could not load driver (undefined method `driver_name' for ODBC:Module)
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:318:in `rescue in load_driver'
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:242:in `load_driver'
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:160:in `_get_full_driver'
    from /home/sa125/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:145:in `connect'
```

Am I missing something here? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out upgrading the vertica gem to the `--pre` version solved the problem of using the first approach. The gem version available through rubygems is (at this time) `0.8.1`, which didn't seem to work well. Based on the feedback I got from the gem's authors, I changed my `Gemfile` from this:

```
gem 'vertica'
```

to this:

```
gem 'vertica', '0.9.0.beta9' # current edge
```