# how to modify dbf files in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dbf

I found https://github.com/infused/dbf is only for reading, is there some ready-made gem that can help me to modify the record of dbf file? I can modify the file by destop software like Gtkdbfeditor, but I would like to do it in Ruby.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this library instead:

https://github.com/spatialnetworks/shp-ruby

Comment: I am glad to hear that's work for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a direct way (so someone else might have a better answer) but I believe there are ODBC connnectors you can use... here's an old [SO Post on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835868/simple-remote-odbc-database-connection-with-ruby)

So if you can install an ODBC driver for your dbs that might be a way forward.

Comment: yep, ODBC is an option for that, but [shp-ruby](https://github.com/spatialnetworks/shp-ruby) is a better choice for me, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Not a problem... I myself am glad to have learned about shp-ruby !  Cheers Steve